# PIC16F877A with SIM800L

Tags: uart

I am having problem with PIC16F877A uart. I am trying to send AT commands to SIM800L but it is returning error. But when I try it with CP2102 module it works fine. Can anybody tell me if something is wrong with my code?

This code with similar logic is  working on LPC2148 but having problem on PIC16F877A.

```
    // CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

char buff[50], a = 0;
char b, *p;
int conn=0;
int i;

#define RS RD0
#define RW RD1
#define EN RD2

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd)
{
    PORTD = (0xF0 & cmd);
    RS = 0;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;

    PORTD = (cmd<<4);
    RS = 0;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;
}

void lcd_data(unsigned char data)
{
    PORTD = (0xF0 & data);
    RS = 1;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;

    PORTD = (data<<4);
    RS = 1;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;
}

void lcd_string(char *str)
{
    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        lcd_data(*str++);
    }
}

void lcd_init()
{
    lcd_cmd(0x02);//return to home
    lcd_cmd(0x28);///4bitmode
    lcd_cmd(0x0C);///cursor off
    lcd_cmd(0x06);///increment cursor
    lcd_cmd(0x01);///display clear
}


void uart_init()
{
    TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1;     ////enable transmission
    TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;     ////high speed selection bit

    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;     ////continuous receive enable

    SPBRG = 129;            ////baud rate generation 9600 at 20MHz crystal
    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1;   ////enable receive(input) on RC7
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 0;   ////enable transmit(output) on RC6

    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1;     ////enable UART 

    GIE = 1;                ///enable UART related interrupts
    PEIE = 1;
    RCIE = 1;
}


void gsm_send_char(unsigned char data)
{
    TXREG = data;
    while(PIR1bits.TXIF ==0);
}

char gsm_receive_char()
{
    while(PIR1bits.RCIF == 0);
    return (RCREG);
}

void gsm_send_string(char *data)
{
    while(*data != '\0')
    {
        gsm_send_char(*data++);
    }
}

__interrupt() void uart(void)
{
    if(RCIF == 1)
    {

        b = RCREG; 
        buff[a] = b;
        a++;
        //buff[a]='\0';

        GIE = 1;
        RCIE = 1;
        PEIE = 1;
        RCIF = 0;        
    }
}

void gsm_init()
{
    if(conn == 0)
    {
        a=0;
        gsm_send_string("AT\r");
        __delay_ms(500);
        if(strstr(buff, "OK"))
        {
            lcd_cmd(0x80);
            lcd_string(buff);
            //a=0;
            memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
        }

        else 
        {
            lcd_cmd(0x80);
            lcd_string("AT ERROR");
        }
    }
}

void main(void) 
{
    TRISD = 0x00;
    lcd_init();
    uart_init();

    lcd_cmd(0x80);
    lcd_string("GSM");

    while(1)
    {
        gsm_init();
        __delay_ms(2000);
    }
    return;
}
```

I tried with changing code little bit and checked for any errors and tried to execute command on flag condition now it does not receive anything in the buffer because it does not print anything. Can anybody tell me why?

```
    // CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f877a.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

#define RS RD0
#define RW RD1
#define EN RD2

//#define AT "AT\"

char buff[80], a;
int flag, b, i = 0;


void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd)
{
    PORTD = (0xF0 & cmd);
    RS = 0;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;

    PORTD = (cmd<<4 & 0xf0);
    RS = 0;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;
}

void lcd_data(unsigned char data)
{
    PORTD = (0xF0 & data);
    RS = 1;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;

    PORTD = (data<<4 & 0xf0);
    RS = 1;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;
}

void lcd_string(char *str)
{
    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        lcd_data(*str++);
    }
}

void lcd_init()
{
    lcd_cmd(0x02);//return to home
    lcd_cmd(0x28);///4bitmode
    lcd_cmd(0x0C);///cursor off
    lcd_cmd(0x01);///display clear
    lcd_cmd(0x06);///increment cursor

}

void uart_init()
{
    SPBRG = 129;
    BRGH = 1;
    SYNC = 0;
    SPEN = 1;
    TXEN = 1;
    CREN = 1;

    GIE = 1;
    PEIE = 1;
    RCIE = 1;
    RCIF = 0;
    //TXIE = 1;

    TRISC7 = 1;
    TRISC6 = 0;
}


void gsm_send_char(unsigned char data)
{
    //////////PORTB = 0xff;
    TXREG = data;
    while(PIR1bits.TXIF == 0);
}

char gsm_receive_char()
{
    while(PIR1bits.RCIF == 0);
    return RCREG;
}


void gsm_send_string(char *p)
{
    while(*p != '\0')
    {
        gsm_send_char(*p++);
    }
}


__interrupt() void isr(void)
{
    if(RCIF == 1)
    {
        a = RCREG;
        buff[i] = a;
        i++;

        if(a == '\r')
        {
            flag = 1;
        }

        if(OERR)
        {
            CREN = 0;
            CREN = 1;
        }

        if(FERR)
        {
            SPEN = 0;
            SPEN = 1;
        }
        RCIF = 0;
        ///////PORTB = 0xff;
    }
}


void main(void) 
{
    TRISD = 0x00;
    //TRISB = 0x00;

    lcd_init();
    uart_init();

    lcd_cmd(0x80);
    lcd_string("GSM TESTING");

    while(1)
    {
        if(flag == 1)
        {
        i = 0;
        gsm_send_string("AT\r\n");
        __delay_ms(400);
        if(strstr(buff, "OK"))
        {
            lcd_cmd(0xC0);
            lcd_string(buff);
            //memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
        }
        else if(strstr(buff, "ERROR"))
        {
            lcd_cmd(0xC0);
            lcd_string(buff);
           // memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
        }
        flag = 0;
    }
    }
    return;
}
```

took reference from this link [enter link description here](https://forum.mikroe.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=19530)

I connected PIC directly to the PC removing SIM800L and ran the code below. It was printing hello when I send hello using putty.

```
   #include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f877a.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

#define RS RD0
#define RW RD1
#define EN RD2


char buff[80], a;
int flag, b, i = 0;


void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd)
{
    PORTD = (0xF0 & cmd);
    RS = 0;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;

    PORTD = (cmd<<4 & 0xf0);
    RS = 0;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;
}

void lcd_data(unsigned char data)
{
    PORTD = (0xF0 & data);
    RS = 1;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;

    PORTD = (data<<4 & 0xf0);
    RS = 1;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(5);
    EN = 0;
}

void lcd_string(char *str)
{
    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        lcd_data(*str++);
    }
}

void lcd_init()
{
    lcd_cmd(0x02);//return to home
    lcd_cmd(0x28);///4bitmode
    lcd_cmd(0x0C);///cursor off
    lcd_cmd(0x01);///display clear
    lcd_cmd(0x06);///increment cursor

}

void uart_init()
{
    SPBRG = 129;
    BRGH = 1;
    SYNC = 0;
    SPEN = 1;
    TXEN = 1;
    CREN = 1;

    GIE = 1;
    PEIE = 1;
    RCIE = 1;
    RCIF = 0;
    //TXIE = 1;

    TRISC7 = 1;
    TRISC6 = 0;
}

void gsm_send_char(char data)
{
    TXREG = data;
    while(TXIF == 0);

}

char gsm_receive_char()
{
    while(PIR1bits.RCIF == 0);
    return RCREG;
}


void gsm_send_string(char *p)
{
    while(*p != '\0')
    {
        gsm_send_char(*p++);
    }
}

__interrupt() void isr(void)
{
    if(RCIF == 1)
    {
        a = RCREG;
        buff[i] = a;
        i++;
        RCIF = 0;
    }
}

void main(void) 
{
    TRISD = 0x00;
    lcd_init();
    uart_init();

    lcd_cmd(0x80);
    lcd_string("GSM TESTING");

    while(1)
    {
        gsm_send_string("AT");
        __delay_ms(400);
        //i = 0;
        if(strstr(buff, "hello"))
        {
            lcd_cmd(0xC0);
            lcd_string(buff);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code looks OK. Just to be clear: do you get *AT ERROR* on the display right after sending `AT\r`?

Comment: Another though: the UART on the PIC you're using works on 5V levels but your modem seems to be 3.3V. Some 3.3V devices will tolerate 5V but others might not, have you tried stepping down the levels on the PIC with resistors?

Comment: In the first code it return AT ERROR because of the else condition but in the second code I checked if sending `AT\r\n` returns any ERROR but I receive nothing neither OK nor ERROR.  I used two methods for logic level first I used a potential divider method and second I used logic level converter.

Comment: I think `strstr()` is returning a NULL pointer because your string is not terminated. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249020/strstr-function-strange-behaviour-in-pic18f)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the terminating character to the string you receive from the UART before using the `strstr()` function.

Something like this should work:

```
    a=0;
    gsm_send_string("AT\r");
    __delay_ms(500);
    buff[sizeof(buff)-1] = '\0';        // Terminate UART buffer with NULL char
    if(strstr(buff, "OK"))
    {
        lcd_cmd(0x80);
        lcd_string(buff);
        //a=0;
        memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    }

    else 
    {
        lcd_cmd(0x80);
        lcd_string("AT ERROR");
    }
```

Depending on the compiler you are using you might also need to change the way you check for a pattern within a string. In my opinion, it would be better to do:

```
if(strstr(buff,"OK") != NULL)
```

Comment: I implemented the same thing and also using potential divider circuit to match logic level of 2.8V on RX pin of SIM800l. I am using XC8 compiler. I tried to check the voltages on the pins during communication the voltages were as expected 2.8V on RX pin of sim800l as it was dropped down and 3.3V on TX pin of sim800l.

Comment: Maybe you have to wait longer than 400 ms for the modem to answer? How long it takes when you connect to your computer? You might also want to verify the UART levels after the voltage divider with a scope if you haven't already

Comment: The Modem reply fine when connected to PC. I have tried with 3sec delay, maybe I need to increase delay beyond 3sec. I do not have access to Scope.

Comment: I think three seconds is more than fair, if it's not working there must be something else. I'm inclined to think you have a hardware issue. What development board are you using for your PIC? Does it have a reliable crystal? Are you sure the SIM800L is running at 9600 bps? Most guides I've seen mention 115200.

Comment: I am using this board [link]https://www.exploreembedded.com/product/PIC16F877A%20Srarter%20Board. It has 20MHz crystal. I have not tried on 115200. I will test it using 115200.

Comment: I see, nice board indeed. Are you using the bootloader or the ICSP? And I guess you are disconnecting the USB port when trying to communicate with the modem, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using the preloaded boot loader and I am disconnecting USB port.

Comment: Maybe you should somehow verify that the UART on the PIC works on its own (not through the CP2102). You can just wire RX to TX and write code to write and read

Comment: I must try that. I tried using PIC16F1936 and programmed it using ICSP it worked fine. I guess I must try to program 877A using ICSP.

Comment: Yes. There might be a conflict between the UART and the bootloader

Comment: I will test it and will post it here if it worked. Meanwhile with PIC16F1936 I am facing some data sending issues, if I am not bothering can you look at the program and rectify the issue. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237575/unable-to-send-continuous-data-on-thingspeak-using-sim800l

Comment: Not at all, but that one is more involved. Have you tried simulating? I will give it a longer go but it looks like a hands-on debugging job

Comment: I tried simulation on Proteus it worked fine on proteus.

Comment: I interfaced SIM800L with 877A on 115200 baud and programmed it using ICSP Pickit3 the problem is still same that is not getting anything in return. On using 115200 baud the error percentage 8%. SO i guess I it will generate more garbage values.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought: 115.2 K is a bit too much for that PIC. You should make sure if the speed of the SIM800 is correct

Comment: Ok I will try it. I am thinking to take the controller out of the board and make a circuit on breadboard or Vero board.

Comment: You can also remove the PIC from the socket and use the CP2102 wiring it from the socket  holes